# WinUSB confused pendrive with external drive?

Tags: usb, windows, hard-drive

Mates,
I was trying to make a windows bootable image on my flash memmory and seems that winusb confused my pendrive with my external hard drive.
The thing is that I've lost like 700gbs. The external drive appears like "Windows USB" when mounted. And doesn't mount at all on Windows.

Can you help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Can you help me with this?

I can tell you that you have formatted your external harddrive and copied the installation files of Windows on it. If you boot from it, you can Install Windows on your PC.

Regarding your lost data, some of it may be recoverable with specific software (like Recuva, Stellar Phoenix Data Recovery on Windows).

> And doesn't mount at all on Windows.

That's weird. Probably some error occured. You can get it back by rewriting partition table and formatting it either with GParted on Ubuntu or DISKPART on Windows.